# Angular How to access controller scope from directives

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular. so stuck to access controller scope from directive.
**$scope.vojta** has been populated in controller which i like to print it from directive.

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer ></my-customer>
</div>

angular.module('docsIsolationExample', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //$scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
  $scope.vojta = { name: 'Vojta', address: '3456 Somewhere Else' };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    /*
    scope: {
      customerInfo: '=info'
    },
    */
    template: 'Name: {{vojta.name}} Address: {{vojta.address}}'

  };
});
```

no name or address is printing. not being able to understand where i made the mistake. looking for some suggestion. here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3g9yddf5/

Comment: Open your browser console. Your code in the fiddle has a syntax error. It's not valid JavaScript. And you forgot to add `ng-app="docsIsolationExample"`in the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have `customerInfo: '=info'` inside isolated scope of directive, you should pass value from `info` attribute(which is use as attribute alias), so that it can available with `customerInfo` scope variable inside a directive.

```
<my-customer info="vojta"></my-customer>
```

And then change directive template to use `customerInfo` which has passed customer info.

```
template: 'Name: {{customerInfo.name}} Address: {{customerInfo.address}}'
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3g9yddf5/2/)

Comment: i tried but id not work. nothing is getting printed.

Comment: i remove info="vojta" from my-customer and comment isolated scope inside directive and it works. i will mark it as answer. thanks

Comment: @Mou no that isn't correct way, if you wanted to create a reusable directive.. have you looked at my updated answer & fiddle?

Comment: i am new in angular. i like to see few example code which show me how many ways communication can happen between controller and directives. suppose like accessing controller function from directive or vice versa.

Comment: give me few article url for the same for me.

Comment: @Mou see here you are expecting too many things in single answer.. I can provide you link which will cover what you wanted.. do look at [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-at) which has well explaination about isolated scope in directive. And one more thing is current [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) are upto, so you can refer them too.

Comment: would u suggest any books which teach me how we can have communication between controller and directive again communication between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

we can access controller scope from directives by the below code without using isolated scope.

```
<div ng-app="docsIsolationExample" ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>

angular.module('docsIsolationExample', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //$scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
  $scope.vojta = { name: 'Vojta', address: '3456 Somewhere Else' };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    /*
    scope: {
      customerInfo: '=info'
    },*/

    template: 'Name: {{vojta.name}} Address: {{vojta.address}}'

  };
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3g9yddf5/3/